# Access to getDateFormat() from controller - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Is it possible to access the getDateFormat() method from a controller or command?

I can use it my models like this:

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
    {
        $format = $this->getDateFormat();   
        return  Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $value, 'UTC')->setTimezone(\Helper::getTimezone());
    }
```

but when using it in my controller or command, like this `$format = getDateFormat();`, I get the following error:

> local.ERROR: exception
>   'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message
>   'Call to undefined function App\Console\Commands\getDateFormat()'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you cannot - cause it's a protected method of Model class.

```
/**
 * Get the format for database stored dates.
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function getDateFormat()
{
    return $this->dateFormat ?: $this->getConnection()->getQueryGrammar()->getDateFormat();
}
```

And by default it's simply

```
/**
 * Get the format for database stored dates.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getDateFormat()
{
    return 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
}
```

Carbon instance uses this format as default so if you need to get Carbon date - just simply use `Carbon::parse($value)` - it will sure recognize this type of format. And by default doing `(string)Carbon::parse($value)` you will get date in this default format cause:

```
/**
 * Format to use for __toString method when type juggling occurs.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected static $toStringFormat = self::DEFAULT_TO_STRING_FORMAT;

/**
 * Format the instance as a string using the set format
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->format(static::$toStringFormat);
}
```

Also check Carbon documentation - there are a lot of modifiers like `->toDateString()`, `->toDateTimeString()`

Answer (score 0):

`getDateFormat()` is not a native function in php if i remeber its use in drupal

so..

if in your $value you have a timestamp you can use `getDate()` this will return an array with minute seconde ...

or if your value isn't timestamp you can use `dateTime()` with format like

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
    {
        $date = new DateTime($value);
        $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
        return $date;

    }
```

I hope this help you
good day

Comment: GetDateFormat() is available is Laravel, like I said, I can use it my models, but not in my controllers. Not sure why